# i want to make the following curl call in my C# application

Tags: c#, facebook, curl

**i want to make the following curl call in my C# application: i beginner of code**
**this code get json response of cities on facebook contain character 'a' and  character 'b' from facebook graph api  i tried to make it i have error The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly  **

```
  private JArray Getcities(string token)
{
    try
    { 

    string s1 = "access_token="+Server.UrlEncode(token);
    string s2 = "&batch=" + Server.UrlEncode(" [ { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\":\"search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=city&region_id=3871&country_code=us&limit=3000&q=a\" }, { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\": \"search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=city&region_id=3871&country_code=us&limit=3000&q=b\" } ]");


         HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/");//make url
        httpRequest.Method = "Post";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "text/json; charset=utf-8";
        byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1 + s2);
        httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;
        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytedata,0,bytedata.Length);
      requestStream.Close();
        StreamReader reader;
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse()

            using (var responsestream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(responsestream, encoding: Encoding.UTF8);
            }


        var apiData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(apiData);
        var data = JArray.Parse(apiData).ToString();
        //var s = data["data"].ToString();
        var x = JArray.Parse(data);
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your using statement

```
using (var responsestream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    reader = new StreamReader(responsestream, encoding: Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

At the end of the using statement the stream gets disposed so it no longer works when you try read to end. It should work if you re-write like this.

```
byte[] apiData; 
using (var responsestream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    reader = new StreamReader(responsestream, encoding: Encoding.UTF8);
    apiData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Then the stream is disposed after reading all the data.

Comment: i can make 20 requests in the same batch with the same way

Comment: Glad to help :) can you mark the question as answered.